# How to add prefix and suffix to the texts inside div using css in Firefox userContent.css

Tags: css, regex, firefox

I need to add a prefix and suffix using css code in Firefox userContent.css file.

Examples before:

```
<div class="label">Royal Blue</div>
<div class="label">Royal Blue/Yellow</div>
```

I need to replace that to:

```
<div class="label">#Royal Blue#</div>
<div class="label">#Royal Blue/Yellow#</div>
```

I need that to search and by searching for #Royal Blue# find exactly this colour not a Royal Blue part in the "Royal Blue/Yellow" so pseudo elements before and after don't work as they are not searchable.

Comment: Hey, to me the tag regex is quite confusing. Do you want to have a snippet of CSS as a solution or a regex to search and replace? It's not 100% clear at this point.

Comment: I added that tag because there is not a one particular text to replace but different texts, so thought that regex may be useful

Answer (score 0):

I am actually still not 100%, sure if that's what you are trying to achieve, but here is a solution afai got it.

```js
// Solution 1
document.querySelectorAll('.case1 .label').forEach(label => {
  label.textContent = `#${label.textContent}#`
});


// Solution 2 (Compatibility)
var labels = document.querySelectorAll('.case2 .label');
var labelCount = labels.length;

for(var i = 0; i < labelCount; i++) {
  labels[i].textContent = '#' + labels[i].textContent + '#';
}
```

```html
<div class="case1">
<div class="label">Royal Blue</div>
<div class="label">Royal Blue/Yellow</div>
</div>
<div class="case2">
<div class="label">Royal Blue</div>
<div class="label">Royal Blue/Yellow</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, that works exactly as I needed, how can I thank you!?

Comment: Just mark it as correct answer, for future people who are having the same problem.

Comment: Just noticed that the search in Firefox doesn't see this added symbol. I need that to search and by searching for #Royal Blue# find exactly this color not a Royal Blue part in the "Royal Blue/Yellow".

Comment: Seems a bit overhead for me, but should now work as expected (just edited the solution)

Comment: It's hard to specifiy the exact problem like this.. What browser are u using and where doesnt it show up? In my example up top or on your side, because my example clearly works in chrome.

Comment: I'm using Pale Moon 24.2.2 because in that version works an older addon "Fastest Search", I'll try in newer Firefox version.

Comment: I just added a backwards compatibility solution.

Comment: In firefox this new version also doesn't work for me, am I doing this correct? 
/* Only for printwear.pl */
@-moz-document domain(printwear.pl) {
    input { min-width: 80px; border: 1px solid red !important; }
document.querySelectorAll('.label').forEach(label => {
  label.textContent = `#${label.textContent}#`
});
}

Comment: It seems like you are trying to write it in your normal CSS code (either inline or in a seperate file) you need to put it in a .js file or script block.

Comment: I'm trying to write it in the chrome/userContent.css - that's the only way I know that I can modify a web page while loading.

Comment: ok, sorry, but I guess that wont be possible that way then. There are couple of browser extensions that can execute scripts at the load of a page tho, that would be the only way I think it would be possbile then. Sorry

Comment: Thank you a lot! I'll try to find those extensions.